# Add new web part in Visual Studio Code project

Tags: sharepoint, visual-studio-code, yo, spfx

I've created a new Sharepoint project with a HelloWorld web part using Yeoman in Visual Studio Code.

Now I want to add another web part to that project.

How do I add a web part using the same template in the src/webparts directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well,

It couldn't get any simplier.

All I have to do is to call `yo @microsoft/sharepoint` once again in the existing project.

Comment: That is correct, but be aware that config.json could overwrite changes you made when running the generator again, keep an eye on those changes